# Debugging stored procedure in SQL group function

Tags: mysql, sql

[[image: Data set [1]]
[image: some samples]

For the **cname='Liam'**, there are **3** card_id
*i.e. 87260101, 87260153, 87501026*
We want to find out how many extra card_id this person has, means we want **output=2**.

For the **cname='Elizabeth'**, there are 2 card_id.
*i.e.87501022, 87501000* and we want an **output of 1**.

For the others who only has one card_id which correspond to an empty loss_report_date,
 **count(loss_report_date)=0**, the **output=0**

For the code below, we get the error code=1111,  invalid use of group function, but the store procedure does not report any error when we run procedure alone.

The DBMS we are using is Innodb.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Gettransaction(IN cname varchar(50),  OUT cnt int)   

BEGIN       
#select card_id if there is no old_id, if t1.card_id=t2.old_id then use card_id 
DECLARE maxcardid char(8);
DECLARE cnt int default 1;
DECLARE nextMax int;

set maxcardid = (select max(card_id) from card
             group by cname);

WHILE cname in (select cname from card where count(loss_report_date)>=1)

DO  
set nextMax = (select max(card_id) 
             from card 
             where card_id < maxcardid);                
set cnt = cnt + 1;      
set maxcardid = nextMax;        
END WHILE;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

call Gettransaction('Liam', @output);
select @output
```

Comment: `set maxcardid = (select max(card_id) from card
             group by cname);` might return multiple rows, must be a single row. Simply remove the `GROUP BY`. `set maxcardid = (select max(card_id) from card
             WHERE cname = :cname);`

Comment: Please specify which sql server you are using? tsql, mysql, and provide the error message you are getting.

Comment: @dnoeth it does not work and still show an error code of 1111, invalid use of group function.

Comment: @steveB Hi, I'm using mysql and the error shown is invalid use of group function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, thank you

Comment: This is probably causing that error: `(select cname from card where count(loss_report_date)>=1)`. Must be `having` instead of `where` and maybe adding `group by cname`. But I doubt you need an SP for this, seems to be a simple Select. Can you add some sample data and expected result?

Comment: @dnoeth adding group by having does not work, when I try calling, it just keeping running without stopping. Some sample data and expected results has been added. Thank you

Comment: Your logic is totally wrong. There's no relation between your Selects and the `cname` parameter. You got an endless WHILE-loop because the data retunred by the Select never changes. `select cname, sum(case when loss_report_date is null then 1 else 0 end) from card group by cname` seems to return what you want for all cnames using a single Select.